# TypeError when implement Unit Test with Jest on NextJS Commerce

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, next.js

I'm currently trying to implement Unit Testing on [NextJS Commerce](https://github.com/vercel/commerce) using Jest for vendure provider.

My component: \components\auth\LoginView.tsx

```
  import useLogin from '@framework/auth/use-login'
  const login = useLogin()
  const handleLogin = async (values: any) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true)
      setMessage('')
      await login({
        ...values,
      })
      setLoading(false)
      closeModal()
    } catch ({ errors }) {
      // @ts-ignore
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }
```

And my test file:

```
import { LoginView } from '@components/auth'
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'

describe('LoginView Component', () => {
  it('renders without error', () => {
    render(<LoginView />)
  })
})
```

I only try to render the component but it keeps appearing the TypeError:

```
TypeError: (0 , _useLogin.default) is not a function for the line: 
 
> const login = useLogin()
```

And similar error for different authentication functions like Forgot Password, Reset Password,... I even try to render Index file and it just doesn't render without error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.